# Maven/Swagger: generate a module (including POM) -- then use it as dep in same build?

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I am using `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` to generate a set of stubs (`java` for client, `jaxrs` for server). I'm doing this by invoking the plugin to generate two Maven projects.

However, the generate **creates** POMs for each generated subproject, and obviously I can't reference them as dependencies in my top-level POM if they don't exist yet!

How is this meant to be done? Does Maven provide a mechanism of picking up dynamically generated submodules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes potentially you can already pre-define a parent pom, if you know the path and the names of the child modules.

step1: Create a maven parent pom to execute multiple sub-modules. Your present swagger based maven build should be a child module under this parent pom.

step2: Make sure the order of execution of the modules defined in parent pom are such that it executes swagger based module first.

step3: Just run the swagger based maven module once first. This will generate the other maven projects. Based on the name of the generated modules and the path of the sub-projects you can reference them in your parent pom now.

step4: Run the aggregated build from the parent pom module. Make sure that a version of the child POM's already exist at the time of first running the aggregated build. Otherwise maven might complain about missing module. I assume that maven loads the child pom files in memory just before starting the respective modules. So this should work.

[Here](http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/maven-multi-module-project/) is an example of multi-module build.

Comment: The tutorial has really a big bug...cause it does not mention to define the build order of the modules by defining the appropriate dependencies between the modules which is also wrong in your recipe with step2. You have to define the correct dependencies between modules and never rely on the modules order within the pom. Always define the correct dependencies between the modules which will automatically lead to the correct build order which Maven will calculate.

Comment: @khmarbaise the bug might be a maven bug in the version you are using? Because I have used the module orders very reliably so far without an issue with maven 3.x

Comment: The problem is not that maven has bug related to the ordering. The problem is simply related to the thing that if you change the module order in the pom your build will fail and defining correct dependencies simply prevents such things...You should never rely on the module order given with a pom file.....

Comment: Thanks everybody!! This was what I pretty much suspected I had to do, although accepted answer was kind enough to do much of the homework for me. I realise that "cleverness" is required, but it seems like in this situation, it's pretty much unavoidable :-/

Answer (score 0):

You're going outside what maven can do.  Maven wants to resolve all modules when loading the parent pom, which is before actually invoking the codegen plugin.  I suggest the following:

- Create the project and the child modules
- Configure the pom.xml in each of the child modules *outside* of the maven plugin
- Have each of the child modules invoke the maven plugin directly instead of from the parent, and configure it to write to the `src/gen/java` folder for output files.

The jaxrs generator will leave the pom.xml if it exists, which will allow you to update it, change dependencies, etc.  If the java client doesn't follow that, then file a ticket in the codegen project, as it should follow the same pattern.